# Merge folders with NSFileManager, overwrite only existing files

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

Basically I am looking for a way to merge two folder in the filesystem with the cocoa API:

I have a folder containing files and sub-folders, which I want to copy to a different location in the filesystem.
At my destination path, an equally-named folder already exists, which may contain files and folders as well.

Now I want to overwrite existing files inside my destination folder (or its subfolders) with the new content of my source folder if they have the same name.
All the rest of the files I want to leave untouched.

```
sourcefolder
   |
   - file1
   - subfolder
       - file2


destinationfolder
   |
   - file3
   - subfolder
       - file2
       - file4


resultingfolder
   |
   - file1
   - file3
   - subfolder
       - file2      <-- version from source folder
       - file4
```

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I searched everywhere but found nothing. So I came up with my own solution, utilizing `NSDirectoryEnumerator`. This should work the diagram (overriding old files). Hope it helps.

```
- (void)mergeContentsOfPath:(NSString *)srcDir intoPath:(NSString *)dstDir error:(NSError**)err {

    NSLog(@"- mergeContentsOfPath: %@\n intoPath: %@", srcDir, dstDir);

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *srcDirEnum = [fm enumeratorAtPath:srcDir];
    NSString *subPath;
    while ((subPath = [srcDirEnum nextObject])) {

        NSLog(@" subPath: %@", subPath);
        NSString *srcFullPath =  [srcDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:subPath];
        NSString *potentialDstPath = [dstDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:subPath];

        // Need to also check if file exists because if it doesn't, value of `isDirectory` is undefined.
        BOOL isDirectory = ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:srcFullPath isDirectory:&isDirectory] && isDirectory);

        // Create directory, or delete existing file and move file to destination
        if (isDirectory) {
            NSLog(@"   create directory");
            [fm createDirectoryAtPath:potentialDstPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:err];
            if (err && *err) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", *err);
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:potentialDstPath]) {
                NSLog(@"   removeItemAtPath");
                [fm removeItemAtPath:potentialDstPath error:err];
                if (err && *err) {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", *err);
                    return;
                }
            }

            NSLog(@"   moveItemAtPath");
            [fm moveItemAtPath:srcFullPath toPath:potentialDstPath error:err];
            if (err && *err) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", *err);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A solution in Swift 3

```
let merger = FoldersMerger(actionType: .copy, conflictResolution: .keepSource)
merger.merge(atPath: sourceFolder, toPath: destinationFolder)


class FoldersMerger {

    enum ActionType { case move, copy }
    enum ConflictResolution { case keepSource, keepDestination }

    private let fileManager = FileManager()
    private var actionType: ActionType!
    private var conflictResolution: ConflictResolution!
    private var deleteEmptyFolders: Bool!

    init(actionType: ActionType = .move, conflictResolution: ConflictResolution = .keepDestination, deleteEmptyFolders: Bool = false) {
        self.actionType = actionType
        self.conflictResolution = conflictResolution
        self.deleteEmptyFolders = deleteEmptyFolders
    }

    func merge(atPath: String, toPath: String) {
        let pathEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: atPath)

        var folders: [String] = [atPath]

        while let relativePath = pathEnumerator?.nextObject() as? String {

            let subItemAtPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: atPath).appendingPathComponent(relativePath).path
            let subItemToPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: toPath).appendingPathComponent(relativePath).path

            if isDir(atPath: subItemAtPath) {

                if deleteEmptyFolders! {
                   folders.append(subItemAtPath)
                }

                if !isDir(atPath: subItemToPath) {
                    do {
                        try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: subItemToPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                        NSLog("FoldersMerger: directory created: %@", subItemToPath)
                    }
                    catch let error {
                        NSLog("ERROR FoldersMerger: %@", error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    NSLog("FoldersMerger: directory %@ already exists", subItemToPath)
                }
            }
            else {

                if isFile(atPath:subItemToPath) && conflictResolution == .keepSource {
                    do {
                        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: subItemToPath)
                        NSLog("FoldersMerger: file deleted: %@", subItemToPath)
                    }
                    catch let error {
                        NSLog("ERROR FoldersMerger: %@", error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }

                do {
                    try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: subItemAtPath, toPath: subItemToPath)
                    NSLog("FoldersMerger: file moved from %@ to %@", subItemAtPath, subItemToPath)
                }
                catch let error {
                    NSLog("ERROR FoldersMerger: %@", error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }

        if deleteEmptyFolders! {
            folders.sort(by: { (path1, path2) -> Bool in
                return path1.characters.split(separator: "/").count < path2.characters.split(separator: "/").count
            })
            while let folderPath = folders.popLast() {
                if isDirEmpty(atPath: folderPath) {
                    do {
                        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: folderPath)
                        NSLog("FoldersMerger: empty dir deleted: %@", folderPath)
                    }
                    catch {
                        NSLog("ERROR FoldersMerger: %@", error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func isDir(atPath: String) -> Bool {
        var isDir: ObjCBool = false
        let exist = fileManager.fileExists(atPath: atPath, isDirectory: &isDir)
        return exist && isDir.boolValue
    }

    private func isFile(atPath: String) -> Bool {
        var isDir: ObjCBool = false
        let exist = fileManager.fileExists(atPath: atPath, isDirectory: &isDir)
        return exist && !isDir.boolValue
    }

    private func isDirEmpty(atPath: String) -> Bool {
        do {
            return try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: atPath).count == 0
        }
        catch _ {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the file manager methods and instead of using the default file manager, create your own with alloc/init, set a delegate, and use the delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I also just found out myself that there are other methods that can do this more cleanly. I will edit my answer.